# sum of a geometric series

Tags: calculus

> check if the series converges and if so what is the sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(6^{\frac{1}{4^{n}}})$$

By the ratio test: $$\frac{\frac{1}{4^{n+1}}\cdot \ln{6}}{\frac{1}{4^{n}}\cdot \ln{6}}=\frac{4^n}{4^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{4}<1$$ it converges.

It is a geometric series so the sum should be?$$\frac{\ln{6}}{1-\frac{1}{4}}$$

Comment: Almost. The first term isn't $\ln 6$ but $(\ln 6)/4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac{\tfrac{\log{6}}{4}}{1-\tfrac{1}{4}}=\frac{\log{6}}{3}$$